# Filling matrix with for loops

Tags: c#, c, arrays, matrix, 2d

Firstly, I fill the array with "0"s and then want to replace the first row with "1"s. Can not understand why the 2nd "for" loop fills the whole matrix with "1"s.

```
int i, j, array[length][width];


for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        array[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    array[0][i] = 1;
}`
```

Comment: It does not set the whole matrix to 1: http://ideone.com/TBq7Ho

Comment: There's a much simpler way to set the entire array to 0: `memset (array, 0, length * width * sizeof(int))`

Comment: There must be a problem with the way you are *looking* at the array, because the code shown is correct.

Comment: Thanks for recommendations and help! In my compiler the same code weirdly did set all to "1", but now it seems to be fine. Thank you again!

Comment: @mch But the problems start to occur when i try to read in the "length" and "width" for user input using "scanf("%d", length)". After input of both of the dimension program crashes. With "#define" it runs perfectly.

Comment: @WeatherVane The problem is that it works perfectly with defined values but crashes with values obtained from user input using "scanf("%d", length/width)".

Comment: `scanf("%d", length/width)` is bad syntax. `scanf` needs the *address* of the target variable. But you are asking a different question now, please **ask a new question**. Is `/` a "divide" or an "or"? The correct syntax is `if (scanf("%d", &width) != 1) exit (1);`

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and it only filled the first row of the matrix with 1's. Try running it again.

Comment: I know that you unfortunately don't have the reputation yet to comment on this question, but for future reference this qualifies more as a comment and less as an answer :)